# Como faço para pedir permissao do usuario, para pegar a localizaçao dele? mostrando um alert com as opçoes permitir ou nao permitir.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aplicação-web

Como faço para pedir permissao do usuario, para pegar a localizaçao dele? mostrando um alert com as opçoes permitir ou nao permitir.

Answer (score 1):

É possível pela [geoLocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) dos navegadores, tal que está acessível no objeto `navigator.geolocation`.

Exemplo da MDN:

**HTML**

```
<p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Exibir minha localização</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

Comment: Ainda N eh isso., quero poder fazer com que o usuario possa permitir a localizaçao dentro da minha aplicaçao., mostranto um popup ou um btn msm... E o usuario clicando permitindo e ligando a localizaçao do navegador e tal'z